# What is the fourier transform of this function?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, exponential-function

With
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{p} e^{-\pi x^2/p^2} $$
and $p>0$, I got an answer of $\displaystyle e^{-\pi p^2u^2}$.

I just wanted to make sure I got the right answer. If I didn't, I will work through the problem and try again. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I checked your function on the Wolfram Alpha. It seems the answer is little bit different. Please check the following link http://bit.ly/Z4KgM8 Good luck.

Comment: @Jdbaba: you do realize his problem is using $\pi$ and not $p*i$, right? :-)

Comment: Plus I tried a fourier transform I already knew on this calculator. It gave me a bizarre answer.

Comment: Note: unless you tell it $p>0$, it will make assumptions for the general case.

Comment: How do you tell it that p > 0? Where would I put it at?

Comment: Using the scaling property, is the answer I got above correct? Assuming you just use the scaling property and the fact that the Fourier transform of $e^{-\pi x^2}$ is $e^{-\pi u^2}$.

Comment: @CameronGarney If you think Wolfram|Alpha is giving you bizarre answers for transforms you know it's possible that you're using different conventions for the transform.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer is correctly derived from the [scaling property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Basic_properties) of the Fourier transform. The function $\exp(-\pi^2 x^2/p^2)$ is $\exp(-\pi x^2)$ scaled by $1/p$. Therefore, the transform scales by $p$ and acquires a factor of $p$, becoming $p\exp(-\pi^2 p^2 x^2)$. Then divide by $p$ throughout.